# Inserting into a HashMap changes the values of every key in the map

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

Trying to make a simple Markov chain for chord progressions. Testing it on a text file whose contents are simply "I IV V" (no newline characters or anything).

I create a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` and populate it with the seven chord values as keys, and with I and V for the values. Printing it out gives this...

```
ii [I, V]
vi [I, V]
V [I, V]
vii [I, V]
iii [I, V]
I [I, V]
IV [I, V]
```

and it reads in the line "I IV V" without issue...

```
Chord: I
Adding IV to I\'s list
Existing values array:
I
V
Updated values array:
I
V
IV
Updated hashtable entry:
[I, V, IV]
```

Everything looks good up to this point. However, when I print out the HashMap after this:

```
Full hashmap:
ii [I, V, IV]
vi [I, V, IV]
V [I, V, IV]
vii [I, V, IV]
iii [I, V, IV]
I [I, V, IV]
IV [I, V, IV]
```

it apparently changed the value of every key in the map, when I only wanted to update the entry for "I" (the other six keys should still map to [I, V]). I know the loops don't make this the easiest job in the world, but I stepped through all of them and I'm still not sure why it's behaving like this. Thoughts?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chords {
    private String[] options = new String[]{"I", "ii", "iii", "IV", "V", "vi", "vii"};
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> chords = new HashMap<>();


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Chords generator = new Chords("data.txt");
    }


    public Chords(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this.chords = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<String> tonic = new ArrayList<>();
        tonic.add("I");
        tonic.add("V");
        for(int i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
            chords.put(options[i], tonic);
        }

        System.out.println("Initial hashmap:");
        for (String str : chords.keySet()) {
            String value = chords.get(str).toString();
            System.out.println(str + " " + value);
        }

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();


        // read in the data
        while(myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("\n\nNEW LINE:");
            String sInput = myScanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(sInput);
            String[] ch = sInput.split(" ");

            // read each line and parse out the chords that follow each one
            for(int i=0; i<ch.length-1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Now looking at chord: " + ch[i]);
                System.out.println("Adding " + ch[i+1] + " to " + ch[i] + "\'s list of following chords");

                temp = chords.get(ch[i]); // retrieve the existing ArrayList of values. We know this is non-null because we pre-populated the HashMap above.

                System.out.println("Existing values array:");
                for(String str : chords.get(ch[i])) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

                temp.add(ch[i+1]); // add the subsequent chord from this data file

                System.out.println("Updated values array:");
                for(String str : temp) {
                    System.out.println(str);
                }

                chords.put(ch[i], temp); // update/overwrite the value array for the given chord

                System.out.println("Updated hashtable entry:");
                System.out.println(chords.get(ch[i]));

                System.out.println("Full hashmap:");
                for (String str : chords.keySet()) {
                    String value = chords.get(str).toString();
                    System.out.println(str + " " + value);
                }
                temp.clear();
            }
        }

        for (String str : chords.keySet()) {
            String value = chords.get(str).toString();
            System.out.println(str + " " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is for all the keys in your map, they all map to one single value (list). So, all the changes you made are being made to the same list.

```
ArrayList<String> tonic = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
  chords.put(options[i], tonic);  <<== tonic 
}
```

Here's what you can do: create a new list for each key.

```
for(int i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
  chords.put(options[i], new ArrayList<String>());   
}
```